# in python 3.4 how to hand over multiple arguments to constraint function in minimize

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to minimize the following function

```
def lower_bound(x, mu, r, sigma):
    mu_h = mu_hat(x, mu, r)
    sigma_h = sigma_hat(x, sigma)
    gauss = np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(10)
    return (1 + mu_h + math.sqrt(2) * sigma_h * min(gauss))
```

where `mu_hat` and `sigma_hat` are some simple helper function for certain calculations. I have the following constraints:

```
cons = ({"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x, mu, r: mu_hat(x, mu, r),
             "args": (arg_dic,)},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x, mu,: -sigma_hat(x, mu),
             "args": (mu,)},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x: x},
            {"type": "ineq",
             "fun": lambda x: 1-np.dot(np.ones(x.size), x)})
```

where `arg_dic` the dictionary of additional arguments

```
arg_dic = {"mu": mu, "sigma": sigma, "r": r}
```

However, when I try to run the following

```
minimize(lower_bound, x0=bounds[t-1, 0],
                        args=(arg_dic, ),
                        constraints=cons)
```

I get the error (in pdb): `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'r'`. But everything is defined. If you print the dictionaries and variables all have a certain value. What is going wrong here?

Comment: from what I can see, `lambda x, mu, r: mu_hat(x, mu, r)` only gets 2 arguments, not 3 when it is called

Answer (score 1):

In `scipy.minimize()` the `args` is a tuple of arguments which are passed to the objective function.  In your case, that function is:

```
def lower_bound(x, mu, r, sigma)
```

And you call it like this:

```
arg_dic = {"mu": mu, "sigma": sigma, "r": r}
args=(arg_dic, )
```

The problem is that you are passing a 1-tuple, which becomes `x`, and no other arguments.  Instead, you should do this:

```
args=(mu, sigma, r)
```

Similarly, you need to fix your constraints, e.g.:

```
cons = ({"type": "ineq",
         "fun": lambda x, mu, r: mu_hat(x, mu, r),
         "args": (mu, r)},
```

Which can be simplified by removing the useless lambda:

```
cons = ({"type": "ineq",
         "fun": mu_hat,
         "args": (mu, r)},
```